# How can I use the command line to see which commit was pushed last

Tags: git

I have been learning to use `git rebase -i` lately to clean up my commits before I push my changes.

However, I find that I am doing `git log`, then checking the remote repo via web gui to see which commit was the last one I pushed, then manually working out how my commits that was so I can use

```
git rebase -i HEAD~[amount]
```

It seems pretty long winded to have to use a web gui to check which commit was the last one pushed* to the remote repo when everything else can be done in command line

Suggestions for a better work flow?

**since the golden rule of rebasing is not to rebase commits already pushed to the repo*

Comment: Edited the title, think it's clearer now. hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `--decorate`

Example `$ git log --decorate`

This will tell you which tag or branch is on which commit in the log overview.

In your case you want to be looking for `origin/master` and/or `origin/HEAD`. They are colored red by default.

---

I always use this command to get a compact and understandable overview of the log history:

```
$ git log --decorate --branches --graph --pretty="oneline" --abbrev-commit
```

It has some other nice parameters that help construct a clear overview. You don't have to use it, but you can try it. It might be very helpful, especially when you work with different branches who have a different history.

In simple scenario's it looks like this (commit messages are substituted in this example)

```
* 9562f31 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Added A
* 57b2de9 Added B
* 687e7d6 Added C
* 187aac7 Added D
* 1fc4a05 Added E
```

in your case the `(origin/master, origin/HEAD` would be a little further down, while `master` and `HEAD` might be at the top.

Answer (score 2):

If you do `git branch -a`, you will see additional branches names, starting with `remote/<remote-name>`. Those are pointing to branches on the selected remote. Now, the thing is, those can be used just like any other tag or branch name.

For example, assume branch `net` that is set to push to remote `origin` branch `network`. It's name will have format `origin/network`. To see last commit pushed there you may use `git show origin/network`. To rebase everything until this commit, try `git rebase -i origin/network`.